# How to make a clone of a square in Javascript

Tags: javascript, cloning

I have an exercise for a web development school, which tells me : "how to clone a square 7 times, and augmenting his number by 1 ( from 1 to 8 then).

I think I need a "while" cycle, with incrementation until i = 8, but I'm not sure. Also, can I create a variable with an html element inside, and then try to duplicate it?

Comment: You're on exactly the right track. Try this for cloning your element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Answer (score 1):

```js
// create the first square and insert it into doc
const square = document.createElement('div');
square.style.width = '50px';
square.style.height = '50px';
square.style.margin = '10px';
square.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
square.innerText = 1;

document.body.appendChild(square);

// simple cycle where i begins from needed number
for (let i = 2; i < 9; i++) {
  const clone = square.cloneNode();
  clone.innerText = i;
  document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this will make clear how to select elements on the page, use a loop to make more, and change what is inside each element.

```js
// Identifies existing HTML elements so JavaScript can interact with them
const container = document.getElementById("container");
const original = document.querySelector(".square");

// Identifies a constant and a variable for our loop
const total = 8;
let number = 1;

// Runs a loop as long as the condition is true
//  (Note: It won't run once number == 8, but the time before that will make square #8)
while(number < total){

  // Changes a value that will effect whether the condition is true
  number++;
  
  // Prints some information about what this iteration of the loop is doing
  console.log("making square number " + number);

  // Makes a copy of an HTML element
  const copy = original.cloneNode();

  // Changes the copy to be different from the original
  copy.innerHTML = number;

  // Adds the copy to the page by appending it to the `container` element
  container.appendChild(copy);  
}
```

```css
.square{
  height: 16px; /* How tall the element will be, not including padding */
  width: 16px;
  padding: 16px; /* How much extra (blue) space the element will include */
  margin: 16px; /* How much extra (white) space the element will have around it */
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center
 }
.blue{
  background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="blue square">1</div>
</div>
```